# Table inside a table row

Tags: reporting-services

I want to put a table inside a table row. But when i try to take the preview it's not working. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Add some more details, so we can answer. What are you trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want a subreport.  You'll need to have a parameter on the subreport that ties to a value in the row that the report is displayed in.  Once you place the subreport in the row in the designer (you'll need to add a detail row for the subreport, I think), you should be able to right-click on the subreport to tell it what report definition to use and how to link the data row to the subreport.